# Integrability in Ito isometry

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

Itō isometry from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C5%8D_isometry):

> Let $W : [0, T] \times \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ denote the canonical
>   real-valued Wiener process defined up to time $T > 0$, and let $X :
>  [0, T] \times \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a stochastic process that is
>   adapted to the natural filtration $\mathcal{F}_{*}^{W}$ of the Wiener
>   process. Then $$
>      \mathbb{E} \left[ \left( \int_{0}^{T} X_{t} \, \mathrm{d} W_{t} \right)^{2} \right] = \mathbb{E} \left[ \int_{0}^{T} X_{t}^{2} \,
>  \mathrm{d} t \right], $$
>
> In other words, the Itō
>   stochastic integral, as a function, is an isometry of normed vector
>   spaces with respect to the norms induced by the inner products $$
>      ( X, Y )_{L^{2} (W)} := \mathbb{E} \left( \int_{0}^{T} X_{t} \, \mathrm{d} W_{t} \int_{0}^{T} Y_{t} \, \mathrm{d} W_{t} \right) =
>  \int_{\Omega} \left( \int_{0}^{T} X_{t} \, \mathrm{d} W_{t}
>  \int_{0}^{T} Y_{t} \, \mathrm{d} W_{t} \right) \mathrm{d} \mathrm P
>  (\omega) $$ and $$
>      ( A, B )_{L^{2} (\Omega)} := \mathbb{E} ( A B ) = \int_{\Omega} A(\omega) B(\omega) \, \mathrm{d} \mathrm P (\omega). $$

Since it suggests an isometry between two normed spaces, I was wondering

- On the LHS, why is the ito integral $\int_{0}^{T} X_{t} \, \mathrm{d} W_{t} $ a $L^2(\Omega)$ function, so that we can talk about its $L^2$ norm?
- On the RHS, does $\mathrm E (\int_0^T X_t^2 dt)$ equal $\int_{\Omega \times [0,T]} X^2 d(\mathrm{P} \times \lambda)$, and $X \in L^2(\Omega \times [0,T])$, so that we can talk about the $L^2(\Omega \times [0,T])$ norm of $X$? Here $\mathrm{P}$ is the probability measure on $\Omega$, $\lambda$ is the restrction of the Lebesgue measure on $[0,T]$, and $\mathrm{P} \times \lambda$ means their product measure. I can't apply Fubini't theorem here, because its conditions seem not apply here.

Note that in Wikipedia version of Ito isometry, the process $X$ is only required to be adapted to the filtration of the Wiener process.  In Shreve's Stochastic Calculus for Finance, the Ito isometry is under the asssumption that $\mathbb{E} [\int_0^T |X(t)|^2 dt] < \infty$. Under both cases, I am not able to figure out the answers to my questions above.

Thanks and regards!

Comment: You seem to mix $\gamma$ and $P$. I am not aware of Ito isometry results for any adapted processes, it seems to be necessary to satisfy some integrability conditions.

Comment: @Ilya: $\gamma$ is from the Wikipedia article, representing the wiener measure when $\Omega := \mathbb R^{[0,T]}$. I use $\mathrm P$ in place of $\gamma$, to allow a more general $\Omega$ which may not be $\mathbb R^{[0,T]}$ or part of it. Could you point out the verion of Ito isometry you have seen, which may need some integrability conditions?

Comment: Oksendal, Corollary 3.1.7 - the same assumption on integrability as in Shreve.

Comment: @Ilya: Thanks! So is the assumption $\mathbb{E} [\int_0^T |X(t)|^2 dt] < \infty$? Then my post was asking: does the assumption imply $\int_0^T |X(t)|^2 dt$ is in $L^2(\Omega)$, and $X$ in $L^2(\Omega \times [0,T])$?

Comment: No, it does not imply that $\int_0^T |X(t)^2|dt$ is in $L^2(\Omega)$, but I don't see why would that be needed. For the second part, what about Fubini?

Comment: @Ilya: I made a typo in my last comment. Is $\int_0^T  X(t) dt$ in $L^2(\Omega)$? For the second, how is Fubini's theorem applied?

Comment: what is unclear to you in the statement of Fubini's theorem?

Comment: @Ilya: Is it to apply Tonelli's theorem, i.e. the condition we need is the integrand $X^2$ to be nonnegative and the measures $\mathrm P$ and $\lambda$ to be sigma finite? So $\int_{\Omega} \int_{[0,T]} X^2 dt d\mathrm P = \int_{\Omega \times [0,T]} X^2 d(\mathrm P \times \lambda)$? Next, by the assumption $\int_{\Omega} \int_{[0,T]} X^2 dt d\mathrm P < \infty$, we then have $X \in L^2(\mathrm P \times \lambda)$?

Comment: @Ilya: (1) On the LHS, is the ito integral $\int_{0}^{T} X_{t} \, \mathrm{d} W_{t} $ a $L^2(\Omega)$ function? (2) Is $\int_0^T X^2 dt$ a Lebesgue integral or a stochastic Rieman integral (i.e Rieman integral of its sample path)?

Comment: I read the article and came to the same question. Have you clarified it in the last 2 years? If there's something to share, you could write an answer and edit the Wikipedia page.